# idangero sliders startAutoplay after swipe not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, slider, mobile-safari, slideshow

Hello, I am using the [iDangero.us Slider](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/) and I have a problem resuming the replay/autoplay after swiping.

Here are the program details: "Create an iPad slider that has autoplay and a clickable pagination button. If the user stops using/swiping the slider, it will resume autoplay without refreshing the page."

```
<script>
    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
        pagination: '.pagination',
        loop:true,
        autoplay: 2000,
        speed:1000,
        autoResize:true,
        paginationClickable: true,
        onTouchStart : function() {
            slideTouched();
        }
    })

    $('.pagination').on('click',function() {
        mySwiper.stopAutoplay();
        mySwiper.params.autoplay = 10000;
        mySwiper.startAutoplay();
    });

    var timer = null;
    function slideTouched(){
        mySwiper.stopAutoplay();
        mySwiper.params.autoplay = 10000
        mySwiper.startAutoplay();
    }
</script>
```

- Link to live demo - http://emannthod.0fees.net/stock1/

I believe the problem is in the function `slideTouched()`.  I don't think `mySwiper` is defined inside of the function. Please help me fix the autoplay feature after swiping.

Answer (score 3):

Set this parameter:

```
autoplayDisableOnInteraction:false
```

Answer (score 1):

Your live demo code in the link you provided has the `slideTouched()` function defined as

```
function slideTouched(){
    Swiper.stopAutoplay();
    Swiper.params.autoplay = 10000
    Swiper.startAutoplay();
}
```

when it should be

```
function slideTouched(){
    mySwiper.stopAutoplay();
    mySwiper.params.autoplay = 10000;
    mySwiper.startAutoplay();
}
```

You want to reference the Swiper object you used to create the slideshow.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, his live demo code was using Swiper instead of mySwiper. If he had written the code on this page in his demo, it would have worked.